# Importing child component into a parent Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to import a test component (It just contains a `<h1>` with some text) into another one, but i get this error:
`[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <EditMachine> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.`

I've tried running the disable cache option in the Network tab in Chrome DevTools, i've named both components, and i've named my Index component.

Here's how the `<EditMachine>` component looks like:

```
export default {
  name: "EditMachine",
  data() {
    return {};
  }
};
</script>
And here's how the parent component looks like:
import EditMachine from "./EditMachine.vue";
export default {
  name: "MachineProfiles",
  data: () => ({
    dialog: false,
    headers: [
      { text: "Number", value: "machine_number", sortable: true },
      { text: "Name", value: "machine_name" },
      { text: "Company", value: "machine_company" },
      { text: "Division", value: "machine_division" },
      { text: "Center", value: "machine_center" },
      { text: "Speed", value: "machine_speed" },
      { text: "CRUD", value: "name", sortable: false }
    ],
    components: {
        EditMachine
    },


Can someone help or at least point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo, the `components` property should be defined on the component scope, but you placed it inside the `data()`

```
export default {
  name: "MachineProfiles",
  data: () => ({
    dialog: false,
    headers: [
      { text: "Number", value: "machine_number", sortable: true },
      { text: "Name", value: "machine_name" },
      { text: "Company", value: "machine_company" },
      { text: "Division", value: "machine_division" },
      { text: "Center", value: "machine_center" },
      { text: "Speed", value: "machine_speed" },
      { text: "CRUD", value: "name", sortable: false }
    ],
  },
  components: {
      EditMachine
  },
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's syntax error judgeing from the code you gave us.

```
export default {
  name: "MachineProfiles",
  data: () => ({
    dialog: false,
    headers: [
      { text: "Number", value: "machine_number", sortable: true },
      { text: "Name", value: "machine_name" },
      { text: "Company", value: "machine_company" },
      { text: "Division", value: "machine_division" },
      { text: "Center", value: "machine_center" },
      { text: "Speed", value: "machine_speed" },
      { text: "CRUD", value: "name", sortable: false }
    ], // <-- Missing closing brackets
    components: {
        EditMachine
    },
```

Try

```
export default {
  name: "MachineProfiles",
  data() {
    dialog: false,
    headers: [
      { text: "Number", value: "machine_number", sortable: true },
      { text: "Name", value: "machine_name" },
      { text: "Company", value: "machine_company" },
      { text: "Division", value: "machine_division" },
      { text: "Center", value: "machine_center" },
      { text: "Speed", value: "machine_speed" },
      { text: "CRUD", value: "name", sortable: false }
    ],
  },
  components: {
      EditMachine
  },
  ...
```

Comment: Hello sir, you are a genius! Your suggestion did not solve my problem, but helped me see that i've placed the components object in the ```data()``` function like the doofus i'm! I've placed it outside and now everything works!